# Plotting circles on 2D matrix with just for loops and list indexing

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using just for loops and list indexing rules, how do I plot this image:

[[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUTY6.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUTY6.png)

It is basically four quarter circles on a 2D matrix. I was only able to plot the first quarter circle in the top left corner, but I'm struggling trying to figure out how to plot the other 3 quarter circles.

```
n = 500
r = n/2
matrix = numpy.zeros((n,n))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i**2 + j**2 <= r**2:
            matrix[i,j] = 1
   
plt.imshow(matrix)
```

Comment: Why did you remove edit I made to include the image inline with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot all the corners at the same time:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i**2 + j**2 <= r**2:  #equation of a circle is x^2 + y^2 = r^2
            matrix[i,j] = 1
            matrix[500-i,j] = 1
            matrix[i,500-j] = 1
            matrix[500-i,500-j] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i**2 + j**2 <= r**2 \
                or i**2 + (n-j)**2 <= r**2 \
                or (n-i)**2 + j**2 <= r**2 \
                or (n-i)**2 + (n-j)**2 <= r**2:
            matrix[i,j] = 1
```

Basically just add condition for three additional circles centered at `(n, 0)`, `(0, n)` and `(n, n)`.